# Electron new-window with sandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, sandbox, new-window

I have weird problem. I can't use 'new-window' for target='_blank' in my app with sandbox and context. Do you know how can i get link from target='_blank' for creating new tab in the app? Rn i have this code but it doesn't work:
**main.js**

```
{...}

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        minWidth: 720,
        minHeight: 480,
        frame: false,
        transparent: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
            nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
            nativeWindowOpen: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            webviewTag: true,
            plugins: true,
            webSecurity: true,
            javascript: true,
            sandbox: true,
            partition: 'some-partition'
        }
    });

{...}

app.on('browser-window-created', (evt, window) => {
    window.webContents.on('new-window', (evt, url) => {
        evt.preventDefault()
        let protocol = require('url').parse(url).protocol;
        if (!protocol.match(/^https?:/)) {
            console.log("invalid url", url);
        } else {
            console.log(url);
        }
    })
})
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: I believe there is no such thing as "new tabs" in Electron, as it is a one-page-like app frame without any url bar or tabs, unlike a regular browser. If you want to open an app page in something that mimics a new tab (or an overlay, maybe better?) you have to create it yourself with html/css. If you mean that you want to pop up a whole new instance of your app frame, then that's another beast and you should edit your post to explain that.

Comment: @anatolhiman i mean, i already have all html/css with react and without sandbox it works fine bc i just send url of 'new-window' to react but with sandbox i just can't get url